# Eigenvalue problem of time dependent Hamiltonian

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quantum-mechanics

I would like to solve an eigenvalue problem of a Hamiltonian. I was able to find the lowest eigenvalue by converting the Hamiltonian into a matrix and applying linear algebra eigenvalue techniques. But this method is extremely cumbersome and does not generalize to arbitrary-sized Hamiltonians. I was hoping somebody could point to a more general approach. Here is the definition of the problem:

Let $\vert \psi_N \rangle$ denote the uniform superposition,
$$\vert \psi_N \rangle  = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum^{N-1}_{i=0}\lvert i \rangle.$$
Then $\vert \psi_N \rangle$ is the ground state of the Hamiltonian $H_0 = I - \lvert \psi_N \rangle \langle \psi_N \lvert$ with the lowest eigenvalue $0$.
Let $\vert m \rangle = \vert 1 0...0 \rangle$. Then it is the ground state of the Hamiltonian $H_m = I - \vert m \rangle \langle m \vert$.

For $ s \in [0,1]$ define the Hamiltonian
$$H(s) = (1-s)H_0 + s H_m.$$

What would be the general approach to solving the following eigenvalue problem for an arbitrary $N$
\begin{align}
H(s) \lvert E_k, s \rangle = E_k(s) \lvert E_k, s\rangle
\end{align}
where $E_k(s)$ is the $k$th eigenvalue at time $s$.

I was able to solve the problem for $N = 4$ by converting the Hamiltonian into a matrix and then using computer algebra I got
$$E_0(s) = \displaystyle \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{3 s^{2} - 3 s + 1}}{2}.$$
The problem with this approach is that it is not general and requires conversion to matrices and then solving the eigenvalue problem. I suspect that it is possible to get the answers in terms of $N$ and $s$ without fixing the size $N$ and expressing the Hamiltonian as a matrix.

Comment: Your Hamiltonian is rank two. Find the action of the Hamiltonian on the vectors $|\psi_N\rangle$ and $|m \rangle$

Comment: It is not rank 2.

Comment: Did you intend for $|\psi_N>$ to have a sum to $N-1$ or should it be $N$?

Comment: Thanks for noting this. Fixed to $N$.

Comment: Forget about the identity part. The rest is rank 2, which means it can be represented as a 2 by 2 matrix

Answer (score 1):

The eigenvalues of $H(s)$ are

$$
1,1,\dots,\frac{1}{2}\left(1\pm\sqrt{1-Cs+Cs^2} \right)
$$

Where

$$
C=\frac{4(N-1)}{N}
$$

**Aside**: Your Hamiltonian has a sort of self-duality: $H_0 \leftrightarrow H_m$, when expressed in terms of the Fourier transformed states

$$
\left|k \right>=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1}e^{-ink}\left|n \right>
$$

With which the transformed Hamiltonian $\tilde{H}$ is

$$
\tilde{H}_0=\mathbb{I}-\left|0 \right> \left< 0\right| \\
\tilde{H}_m=\mathbb{I}-\left|\phi_K \right> \left< \phi_K\right|
$$

Here $\left|\phi_K \right>$ denotes the uniform superposition of $k$ states. Consequently

$$
H(s)=\tilde{H}(1-s)
$$